# links scroll to a div (class) and just one scroll (animate) in a different direction

Tags: jquery, class, scrollto

I am trying to have quite a few links scroll to a div and just one scroll (animate) in a different direction.

My html would look like this:

```
<div class="top"> content here </div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="link1" class="bottom">link2</li>
  <li><a href="link2" class="bottom">link3</li>
  <li><a href="link3" class="bottom">link4</li>
  <li><a href="link4" class="bottom">link5</li>
  <li><a href="link5" class="bottom">link6</li>
</ul>

<p> content here </p>
<p> content here </p>
<p> content here </p>
<p> etc... </p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="link6" class="top">link1</li>
</ul>

<p> content here </p>
<p> content here </p>
<p> content here </p>
<p> etc... </p>

<div class="top"> content here </div>
```

So links2, 3, 4, 5, & 6 would scroll to the div class="bottom".

Link6 would scroll to the top div class="top".

I can't change the link itself, so it has to work by using the class names:

class="bottom"

class="top"

How would this be achieve with jQuery?

Also... I don't want to use ID's in the links or div's.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.scrollby(nHorizontal, nVertical); in a click handler with setTimout(). like this :

```
$(".bottom").click(function() 
{ 
    setTimeout(500. function() { window.scrollBy(nHorizontal, nVertial) }); 
}).
```

and change the href of your links to #divBottom and put the id on the div.

The setTimeout is to give time for the initial scroll of the page.

Another method is shown on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Code :

```
$(function() 
{
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() 
  {
    var nDistance = 0; // Set to whatever distance this needs to scroll.

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    &&  location.hostname == this.hostname) 
    {
      var aAnchor = $(this)
      var target  = $(this.hash.replace("#", ".")); // get target by class name

      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

      if (target.length) 
      {
          $('body').animate(
          {
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 
          1000,
          function()
          {
             $("body").animate({ scrollTop: nDistance }, 500);                 
          });
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

if you want to get really inventive, set a data attribute on the anchor telling each individual anchor how far to scroll.

html

```
<a href="#divBottom" data-scrollDistance="350" > Text <a/>
```

javascript to access from click handler

```
$(this).data("scrollDistance");
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I don't want to use ID's. Plus, I can't change the link href's.

Comment: Updated with solution to fit criteria completely. the top information fits the title so that future visitors may find their answer. I have one more adjustment to myanswer and it will solve your issue. :)

Comment: There ya go! Sorry about the initial answer being off, I needed to get the answer I would expect coming to the question on here. But the solution under that shows the answer you need.

Comment: Corrected issue of double call from selector.